# How to include both category and page in page's menu in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new in WordPress, but it's about 5 years that I am doing programming. One of my friend asked me to make a website for her using WordPress and I don't know if I can do it or not because *I am not professional and maybe do something wrong in WordPress that has bad effect in the feature.*

It is some days that I am reading and working with WordPress, and I know a little about it but I get confusing!

---

Now I know about tag, category, page and something else. I know that I can create page and sub page, (so on) category and sub category. As I got pages are for static contents and when I make a page their links with titles will show in a place *(in the 2014 theme the links will show in the top navigation bar)*

Imagine the website is for a travel agency and this should be my menu:

**Visa [p] | Tours [c] | Hotels [c] | Women only tours [p] | Blog [c] | About us [p] | Contact us [p]**

> *point: c means category and p means page

As you see I am going to use the menu and have both categories and pages in my menu (same as the way that pages' link title is shown in WordPress)

**How to include both category and page in page's menu *(I mean nav bar)* in WordPress?**

**[OR] Is there any way that (for example) a page gets its content from a URL or category?**

*I am not professional in WordPress and this website, I hope you don't mind and don't give me down vote*

Comment: Ok, I if you have created the pages, categories (and added some posts), you can go to the mentioned Appearance > Menu and add them to the menu (don't forget to save). P.S. I can't image having Contact page as category.

Answer (score 0):

You can add categories directly to nav menus from the `Menu` page under the `Appearance` tab in the admin dashboard. [This page](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) mentions that categories might be hidden under the `Screen Options` found sort of near the top (see below). I hope this is what you meant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create category regularly in dashboard.

Then in Appearence-Menu, look at your left you will see "personalized link" or "customed link" something like that.
Go to categories, display them to get their adress link
Paste  each these links in on personalized button created.

Hope it's clear, my english suck